# Parsing CSV File and Maintaining An Average

Tags: python, csv

`For each day compute the average of 'new_cases' of the previous 7 days for every location. (if there are less than 7 days from the current day, calculate the average from the beginning of the first case in that location to the current day)`

I'm trying to solve this problem using python. I need to parse a CSV file which has the following information:

`date,location,new_cases,new_deaths,total_cases,total_deaths,weekly_cases,weekly_deaths,biweekly_cases,biweekly_deaths`

and for each country, on each day compute the average of new_cases from the previous 7 days (or if it hasn't been 7 days yet, then how many ever days it has been so far).

I've been able to mantain a dictionary for each country that contains the new_cases on each day in the CSV. For example: `'China': [{'2019-12-31': '27'}, {'2020-01-01': '0'}, {'2020-01-02': '0'}, {'2020-01-03': '17'}], 'Finland': [{'2019-12-31': '0'}, {'2020-01-01': '0'}, {'2020-01-02': '0'}, {'2020-01-03': '0'}]`.

I'm struggling on getting to the part where I can compute the average of the previous 7 days for every day for every location. Here is my code so far:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)

    country_dict = {}

    for line in csv_reader:
        date = line[0]
        country = line[1]
        new_cases = line[2] if line[2] != '' else 0

        if country not in country_dict:
            country_dict[country] = [{date: new_cases}]
        else:
            country_dict[country].append({date: new_cases})
    
    print(country_dict)
```

I'm new to python so I'm looking to solve this without any complicated functions / lambdas. Thanks!

Comment: use `pandas` for convertcvs file into Dataframe which is data type in pandas
and then you can do alot of proccessing in this  data (avg,mean,count,...etc)
for more see the docmetation https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I can't use pandas for this, only allowed to use the csv library

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your code does a decent job so far. Your only issue is in calculating the running total. To do that, we just need to make some small adjustments to your existing code. First, instead of using a dictionary to store your data, we should create a class:

```
class DateEntry:
    def __init__(self, date, daily_cases, running_total):
        self.date = date
        self.daily_cases = daily_cases
        self.running_total = running_total
```

This will make working with your data much easier. Next, let's inject this code into your calculation and add in the running total calculations:

```
for line in csv_reader:
    date = line[0]
    country = line[1]
    new_cases = int(line[2]) if line[2] != '' else 0

    if country in country_dict:
        country_dict[country].append(DateEntry(date, new_cases, 0))
    else:
        country_dict[country] = [DateEntry(date, new_cases, 0)]

for country, entries in country_dict.items():
    sorted(entries, key = lambda e: e.date)
    for i in range(0, len(entries)):
        entries[i].running_total = sum(
            map(lambda e: e.daily_cases, entries[max(i - 6, 0):i]), 
                entries[i].daily_cases) # Calculation step
```

With the exception of me switching the cases on your if-else statement and the inclusion of the usage of the class object, the only change here is the second for-loop. This loop iterates over all the data associated with each country, sorts the entries by oldest to newest (you don't need to do this step if your data is already sorted) and then calculates the running total for each. The calculation step works like this:

1. `entries[max(i - 6, 0):i]` retrieves the last six entries (so the last six days of data) or from the beginning of the list if there aren't six entries available.
2. `map(lambda e: e.daily_cases, entries[max(i - 6, 0):i])` converts the list of `DateEntry` objects to a list of integers where each integer represents the daily cases associated with the entry
3. `sum(map(lambda e: e.daily_cases, entries[max(i - 6, 0):i]), entries[i].daily_cases)` adds up all the cases of the last six days and then adds the cases from the current day to that total

Alternatively, if you want to get the same results without all the lambda functions, you could do it like this:

```
for country, entries in country_dict.items():
    sorted(entries, key = lambda e: e.date)
    for i in range(0, len(entries)):
        entries[i].running_total = entries[i].daily_cases
        for entry in entries[max(i - 6, 0):i]:
            entries[i].running_total += entry.daily_cases
```